# Is it possible to check (serverside) if a laravel-websockets channel is ocupied?

Tags: android, laravel, websocket, channel, pusher

I'm using Laravel-Websockets to send Events to an android-devices. 
To send an event, i am triggering laravel events like

```
event(new ExampleEvent($message, $channel));
```

and $channel defines the channelname to broadcast the event. A channel is just for one device. So there is a maximum of one device listening to a channel.

On my webapp i want to show which android devices are online. My Idea is to check if the channel of a specific device is occupied.

Is it possible to check if a channel is occupied?

Comment: In same situation. Did you find any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to find out if a channel has active subscriptions (is occupied) using the HTTP API. You can use the Get channels endpoint as shown at the link below. This will return the full list of channels that currently exist (so are occupied).

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/http-api#application-channels

You can periodically poll this endpoint and store the list of channels that are returned as being occupied on your server.

Finally so you don't need to poll the API too frequently you can receive updates about channels that have become occupied or vacated since you last polled the API by setting up a channel existence event webhook. This can be done from "webhooks" tab of your Channels app in your account dashboard:

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks

a) When a Channel goes from having 0 subscribers to 1 subscriber it will come into existence and the channel_occupied webhook will be fired. You can capture this event on your server and add this to your list of channels that are occupied.

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks#channel-occupied

b) When the channel goes from having at least 1 subscriber to 0 subscribers, the channel will cease to exist and you will receive a channel_vacated event. You can remove the vacated channel from your list of occupied channels:

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks#channel-vacated

Comment: This is working if i am using the pusher-server, but is this also working if i am using my self hosted laravel-websockets server?